# How to properly set a breakpoint in a nested class using JDB?

Tags: java, android, debugging, jdb

```
package com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection;

public abstract class DcTrackerBase extends Handler {
    protected BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver ()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DBG) log("onReceive: action=" + action);
[...]
```

In the above code, using `jdb`, I'd like to set a breakpoint on the `onReceive` method. I used the following command :

```
> stop in com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase$mIntentReceiver.onReceive
```

And I get this from `jdb` :

```
> Deferring breakpoint com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase$mIntentReceiver.onReceive.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
```

I know that the class is already loaded, so I imagine that jdb is not finding the method I want. How should I set my breakpoint then ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wrangled method name is wrong.

In JDB, issue this command to inspect the `DcTrackerBase` class :

```
> class com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase
Class: com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase
extends: android.os.Handler
subclass: com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTracker
nested: com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase$1
```

As we can see, the nested class `DcTrackerBase$1` could be our `BroadcastReceiver` class. To verify, issue the following command :

```
> class com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase$1
Class: com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase$1
extends: android.content.BroadcastReceiver
```

That's it ! To set the breakpoint properly, we type :

```
> stop in com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase$1.onReceive
Set breakpoint com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase$1.onReceive
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an anonymous class when you override the onReceive like in the above code. This should create a class with a name in the form DcTrackerBase$(a number) depending on how many other anonymous/inner classes you have in DcTrackerBase.java file. I wrote an example to replicate your problem.

```
public class DebugFun{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object myObj = new Object(){

            public String toString(){
                int x = 1;
                x++;
                return "X is:"+x;               
            }
        };
        System.out.println(myObj);

    }


}
```

Then call

```
jdb DebugFun
```

to start the debugger then:

```
stop in DebugFun$1.toString
run
```

And now the debugger is inside the internal class.